# My HTML for vertically aligning each heading isn’t working

Tags: html

My code worked until now, and I don’t understand what’s happened. I’m trying to vertically align each heading, next to each other. I’d really appreciate someone giving me a hand with this, please!

```html
<div style="width: 32%; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; text-align:;">
  <h3>Gents</h3>
  <p>
    <a href="barberp6.html">
      <span style="color:rgb(245, 166, 208);">The</span>
      <span style="color: rgb(167, 238, 220);">Baber</span>
      <span style="color:rgb(188, 114, 223);">Shop</span>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [validate your HTML](https://html5.validator.nu/) before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by flexbox
Assume `vertical-align` is the class you gonna have

`.vertical-align{
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
    }`

Comment: It doesn't seem to have worked! I'm still leaning. Could you tell me if I need to change any HTML code? Thanks :)

Comment: Better to follow some beginner level tutorials and come across this site. https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/ follow this link for tutorials and understand the concept behind it

Comment: I'll take a look! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you put a `<br>` in between every single span element like this:

```html
<div style="width: 32%; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; text-align:;">
  <h3>Gents</h3>
  <p>
    <a href="barberp6.html">
      <span style="color:rgb(245, 166, 208);">The</span>
      <br>
      <span style="color: rgb(167, 238, 220);">Baber</span>
      <br>
      <span style="color:rgb(188, 114, 223);">Shop</span>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

This creates a space in between every word. I can't find any other way...

Comment: It doesn't seem to work either! I'm totally lost. I'll have to keep looking, and hopefully i'll come across the answer! Thank you :)